# Including white spaces using sscanf

Tags: c++, scanf

Code is

```
sscanf(szbuf, "%s %c %s", szTmp1, &szChar, szTmp2);
```

where 
szubuff is `fetch_query = SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1`

szChar is `=`

`szbuf`, `szTmp1`, `szTmp2` are character arrays.
Problem is that szTmp2 is storing only `SELECT` and ignoring the rest.
But I need complete `SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1` inside `szTmp2`

Comment: Are you sure you're programming in C++ ?

Comment: @LihO : Absolutely :)

Comment: See my answer to understand why I asked that question and why that comment is getting upvotes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    char str[] = "fetch_query = SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1";
    char *qry, *sql; 
    qry = strtok(str, "=");
    sql = strtok(0, "=");
    printf("%s -- %s\n", qry, sql);
    return 0;
}
```

*Output:*

```
fetch_query  --  SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this. It matches all characters to the end of line:

```
sscanf(szbuf, "%s %c %[^\n]", szTmp1, &szChar, szTmp2);
```

Comment: Nope. Still same problem :(
Executing the query SELECT          
Exception : ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: @MM. I wonder how your code is working when szChar is not defined !!

Comment: @sajal `szChar` in that code is *defined*, it's just not initialized. But that's fine, because `sscanf` does not care about current value, it receives just the address for storing new value there.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using C++, you should consider using objects of type `std::string` instead of C-style strings and parsing the string with the format `" var = value "` could be done using the string stream the following way:

```
std::istringstream is("fetch_query = SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1");
std::string var, divider, value;
if ((is >> var >> divider) && divider == "=")                          // check 1
{
    std::getline(is, value);
    if (!value.empty())                                                // check 2
        std::cout << "var name: " << var << std::endl
                  << "value :" << value << std::endl;
}
```

The "check 1" condition ensures that 2 words are extracted from the stream and the second one is equal to the string `"="`. The "check 2" ensures that after the `"="` there is at least 1 more word.

In this case it outputs:

```
var name: fetch_query
value : SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1
```

PS: The above example requires `#include <iostream>` and `#include <sstream>`.

Answer (score 0):

The %s in sscanf only reads a word at a time, i.e. it stops on the first whitespace. Instead you can use something like the following:

```
sscanf(szbuf, "%s %c %[0-9a-zA-Z ]", szTmp1, &szChar, szTmp2);
```

where the %[0-9a-zA-Z ] says to keep reading as long as the characters in the input are found in the specification (a-z is a range of characters).